# Disconnection with Strophe.js

Tags: typescript, angular6, xmpp, strophe

I am using typescript, angular6 and strophe.js(xmpp) for web application. Initially Strophe works fine and establishes connection, but after sometime(10 to 15 minutes later) it disconnects and establishes connection only after page refresh.
Is there any solution to establish connection immediately after disconnection?